# Associative Arrays and the "foreach" statement

Tags: php

I'm watching a PHP tutorial, and when the instructor puts this code in:

foreach ($_POST as $key => $instanceValue)

I was wondering if this means that $_POST is already an associative array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $_POST is a superglobal associative array

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be answered by reading the manual, or google, in less time than it took to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you test it?

```
<pre>
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
</pre>
```

The official manual says:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: That's a good idea to test it with print_r.  I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) for `$_POST`:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

So, yes, `$_POST` is already an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via
>   the HTTP POST method.

Comment: `$HTTP_POST_VARS` is  deprecated. NOT `$_POST`